# Connection with google drive with an android installed application

Tags: cordova, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

We are trying to create an application that requires Google Drive service, and thus requires authentication.

The application runs on a web server, following the steps in this url: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/quickstart-js and we used the code shown in the url.
However on a mobile device, using the same steps, we have created another client ID for installed application, and we do not get access to Google services. (We get a blank screen).

Furthermore we tested another sample code also extracted from Google, it connects to Google services with our `CUSTOMER_ID` and `REDIRECT_URI` ***"urn: ietf: wg: oauth: 2.0: oob"*** and we got this message on screen:

```
Please copy this code, switch to your application and past it there

4/v..........
```

After reading the Google documentation, we're recommended adding `":auto"` to `REDIRECT_URI` (which becomes ***"urn: ietf: wg: oauth: 2.0: oob: auto"***) to close that window and go back to our application with a validated authorization, but the google's window doesn't close and we get this message:

```
Permission has been granted correctly.

Changes to your application
```

Here's the code we used:

```
var googleapi = {
    authorize: function(options) {
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        //Build the OAuth consent page URL
        var authUrl = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?'
                + $.param({
            client_id: options.client_id,
            redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
            response_type: 'code',
            scope: options.scope
        });
        //Open the OAuth consent page in the InAppBrowser
        var authWindow = window.open(authUrl, '_blank',
            'location=no,toolbar=no');
        $(authWindow).on('loadstart', function(e) {
            var url = e.originalEvent.url;
            var code = /\?code=(.+)$/.exec(url);
            var error = /\?error=(.+)$/.exec(url);
            if (code || error) {
                //Always close the browser when match is found
                authWindow.close();
            }
            if (code) {
                //Exchange the authorization code for an access token
                $.post('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token', {
                    code: code[1],
                    client_id: options.client_id,
                    client_secret: options.client_secret,
                    redirect_uri: options.redirect_uri,
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code'
                }).done(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                    authWindow.close();
                }).fail(function(response) {
                    deferred.reject(response.responseJSON);
                });
            } else if (error) {
                //The user denied access to the app
                deferred.reject({
                    error: error[1]
                });
            }
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    }
};
$(document).on('deviceready', function() {
    var $loginButton = $('#login a');
    var $loginStatus = $('#login p');
    $loginButton.on('click', function() {
        googleapi.authorize({
            client_id: '******************.apps.googleusercontent.com',
            client_secret: '************************',
            redirect_uri: 'urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob:auto',
            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'
        }).done(function(data) {
            $loginStatus.html('Access Token: ' + data.access_token);
        }).fail(function(data) {
            $loginStatus.html(data.error);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get authorized to Google Drive from an Android application by using one of OAuth's web and mobile SDK's, which have really helped me out recently: https://oauth.io/. You use web credentials from the Google Development Console to register your app on OAuth, then they provide a mobile SDK so that you can access the authentication successfully.

Comment: ThankU very much. We've not got it yet, but we thank your effor and your answer.